# Running mysqld as a different user (on fedora) creates issues with data directory

Tags: mysql, permissions

Using the configuration file my.cnf, I've set mysql to run as a different user. It works fine, only every time I restart the daemon it changes ownership of the mysql data directory to mysql.mysql and removes write permissions for the group.
The end result is it runs as a different user unable to write to its own data.

Does anybody understand what's going on here? Is this a mysql bug? A fedora issue? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I don't have a Fedora box handy.  Is there an /etc/sysconfig/mysql(d) that might tell the /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld script to enforce ownership on the data directories to mysql:mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora's (and RHEL/CentOS) MySQL init script (**/etc/init.d/mysql**) changes ownership and permissions of the data directory on startup.

You can open the file and comment out the lines you don't need, but then you should be careful when you update your MySQL package, because your changes may be overwritten.

Comment: That's very strange. Do you think I'm the first person running into this problem? What do other people do if they want to easily copy paste data directories as an ordinary user?

Comment: Maybe set up and use sudo? Or just remember to edit **/etc/init.d/mysql** every time when you update the *mysql-server* package.

Answer (score 1):

If you run mysql as a different user to be able to copy the data from the ordinary user, consider adding this user to group `mysql' and leave mysql running as`mysql.mysql'.